# C++ compile issues

Tags: c++, data-structures

Hello I am getting compile errors and I don't understand why

- 2   IntelliSense: expected an identifier    c:\Users\Sean\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\mystring\mystring\mystring.cpp  93  7   mystring
- 3   IntelliSense: expected a ';'    c:\Users\Sean\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\mystring\mystring\mystring.cpp  93  10  mystring
- 4   IntelliSense: member function "main_savitch_4::mystring::operator=" may not be redeclared outside its class c:\Users\Sean\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\mystring\mystring\mystring.cpp  106 17  mystring
- 5   IntelliSense: expected a ';'    c:\Users\Sean\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\mystring\mystring\mystring.cpp  107 2   mystring
- 6   IntelliSense: more than one operator ">>" matches these operands:
          function "operator>>(std::istream &ins, main_savitch_4::mystring &target)"
          function "main_savitch_4::operator>>(std::istream &ins, main_savitch_4::mystring &target)"
          operand types are: std::istream >> main_savitch_4::mystring c:\Users\Sean\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\mystring\mystring\mystring.cpp  246 7   mystring

  ```
  #include <iostream>
  #include "mystring.h"
  #include <cstring>
  using namespace std;
  using namespace main_savitch_4;


  //Constructors- sets initial values for memeber variables

    mystring::mystring(const char str[] = "")

  //returns a pointer referencing [0] in an array
  {
  current_length = 0;
  int pt = 0;

  if (str[pt] != '\0') //this increases the array size to the string size
  {
      ++current_length;
      ++pt;
  }

  sequence = new char[current_length + 1];
  while (current_length >= pt)
  {
      sequence[pt] = str[pt];
      ++pt;
  }
  allocated = current_length + 1;
  }

  mystring::mystring(const mystring& source)
  {
  sequence = new char[source.allocated];
  current_length = source.current_length; //returns mystring object with same
  allocated = source.allocated;           //length and allocation as source
  for (int i = 0; i <= allocated; ++i)
  {
      sequence[i] = source.sequence[i]; //copies characters to new object
  }

  }

  //Destructor- frees space
  mystring::~mystring()
  {
          delete[] sequence;
  }

  void mystring::operator +=(const mystring& addend)//adds another string ontop of the original
  {

  reserve(current_length + addend.current_length + 1);
  strcpy(sequence + current_length, addend.sequence);
  current_length += addend.current_length;
  }
      void mystring::operator +=(const char addend[])
      {
  int leng = current_length + strlen(addend);
  if (leng >= allocated)
          {
      reserve(leng + 1);
  }

  strcpy(sequence + current_length, addend);
  current_length = leng;
  }

  void mystring::operator +=(char addend)
  {
  while (current_length >= allocated)
  {
      reserve(current_length + 1);
  }

  sequence[current_length] = addend;
  sequence[current_length + 1] = '\0'; //increases size to allow for \0     character
  ++current_length;

          }   

   void mystring::reserve(size_t n) //size_t represents the size of object
  // n is the size


  {

      if (allocated < n)
      {

      char[] sequence = new char[n];
      for (int i = 0; i <= current_length; ++i)
      {
          sequence + i;
          allocated = n;
      }

  }


  /////////////////////


  void mystring::operator =(const mystring& source)
  {

      delete[] sequence;
      sequence = new char[source.allocated];
      allocated = source.allocated;
      current_length = source.current_length;

      for (int idx = 0; idx <= source.allocated; ++idx)
      {
          sequence[idx] = source.sequence[idx];
      }

  }



  char mystring::operator [ ](size_t position) const

  {
      return sequence[position];
  }


  std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& outs, const mystring& source)

  {
      outs << source.sequence;

      return outs;
  }

  bool operator ==(const mystring& s1, const mystring& s2)

  {
      int length = 0;
      bool gate = false;


      if (s1.length() >= s2.length())
          length = s1.length();
      else
          length = s2.length();

      for (int idx = 0; idx < length; ++idx)
      {
          if (s1[idx] - s2[idx] == 0 && idx == length - 1)
              gate = true;
      }

      return gate;
  }

  bool operator !=(const mystring& s1, const mystring& s2)

  {
      return !(s1 == s2);
  }

  bool operator >=(const mystring& s1, const mystring& s2)

  {
      if (s1 < s2)
          return false;
      else
          return true;
  }

  bool operator <=(const mystring& s1, const mystring& s2)

  {
      if (s1 > s2)
          return false;
      else
          return true;
  }

  bool operator > (const mystring& s1, const mystring& s2)

  {
      bool gate = false;
      int length = 0;

      if (s1.length() <= s2.length())
          length = s1.length();
      else if (s1.length() > s2.length())
          length = s2.length();

      for (int idx = 0; idx < length; ++idx)
      {
          if (s1[idx] - s2[idx] < 0)
          {
              gate = true;
              idx = length;
          }
          else if (idx == length - 1 && s1.length() < s2.length())
          {
              gate = true;
          }
      }

      return gate;
  }

  bool operator < (const mystring& s1, const mystring& s2)

  {
      if (s1 != s2 && s2 > s1)
          return true;
      return false;
  }


  mystring operator +(const mystring& s1, const mystring& s2)

  {
      mystring temp(s1);
      temp += s2;
      return temp;
  }

  std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& ins, mystring& target)

  {
      while (ins && isspace(ins.peek()))
      {
          ins.ignore();
      }

      target = ""; //Clear out any junk in the target

      while (ins.peek() != '\n')
          target += ins.get();

      return ins;
  }

  std::istream& getline(std::istream& ins, mystring& target)

  {
      ins >> target;

      return ins;
  }
  ```

Comment: Intellisense errors are not compiler errors.  Post the actual compiler errors (errors starting with the letter `C`).

Comment: A good strategy is to remove code until the error stops and then slowly start adding it again.

Comment: Please don't just dump all your code into a question, post a [mcve] instead.

Answer (score 1):

This if statement in function reserve:

```
void mystring::reserve(size_t n)
{
    if (allocated < n)
    {

    char[] sequence = new char[n];
    for (int i = 0; i <= current_length; ++i)
    {
        sequence + i;
        allocated = n;
    }
}
```

Doesn't appear to be closed. Try adding a }.

Comment: `char[] sequence = new char[n];`  When was this ever valid C++?